# How can I change the background color for every second column in Tkinter, treeview?

Tags: tkinter, treeview, python-3.7

I need to change every second column's background color.

```
columns = ('ID', 'type', 'name', 'CECQ code', 'QR code', 'location', 'placement', 'edition date', 'description', 'Check')
listBox = Treeview(content, columns=columns, show='headings', height=50)
listBox.pack(fill='y', expand=True, side=LEFT)
```

[Enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlQ1s.png)

I am using the *insert* method and tried to do it using tags, but it seems impossible.

Comment: `Treeview` does not support different colors on different columns.

Comment: (Note: The screenshot [is OK here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/) as it is of a user interface, not program input or program text output.)